# 'is_trivial_v' is not a member of 'std' while build C++ project with conan

Tags: c++, conan

I'm trying to write C++ project with conan. I need to use qt/6.2.2 as dependency.
After I run

```
conan create . user/test
```

It comes out a long error message. The last few lines are:

```
/home/run/.conan/data/qt/6.2.2/_/_/package/e1b261f6f4c131503719b972012039d1853778f9/include/QtCore/qarraydatapointer.h:374:27: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const T’ (‘int’ and ‘qsizetype’ {aka ‘long long int’})
  374 |                 ? n + qMax(0, (header->alloc - from.size - n) / 2)
      |                       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Wuziqi.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/Wuziqi.dir/Wuziqi.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/Wuziqi.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
Wuziqi/1.0.0@user/test: 
Wuziqi/1.0.0@user/test: ERROR: Package '702f20c11c28f19fd5e1d929272b0f47e81fec21' build failed
Wuziqi/1.0.0@user/test: WARN: Build folder /home/run/.conan/data/Wuziqi/1.0.0/user/test/build/702f20c11c28f19fd5e1d929272b0f47e81fec21
ERROR: Wuziqi/1.0.0@user/test: Error in build() method, line 26
    cmake.build()
    ConanException: Error 2 while executing cmake --build '/home/run/.conan/data/Wuziqi/1.0.0/user/test/build/702f20c11c28f19fd5e1d929272b0f47e81fec21' '--' '-j12'
```

There are multiple errors in the middle, like:

```
error: ‘is_integral_v’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘is_integral’?
  170 |         template <typename Int> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Int>, iterator>
```

```
error: ‘compare_eq_result_container’ in namespace ‘QTypeTraits’ does not name a template type
  306 |     QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList, U> operator==(const QList &other) const
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
error: ‘is_same_v’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘is_same’?
  285 |                 if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<InputIterator>, iterator> ||
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                    is_same
```

Does it seem that there is no xxx_v in std?
How could I fix it?

Comment: You need -std=c++17.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Does your project use cmake or qmake as a build system?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thanks for your suggestion but it said c++17 is not an option

Comment: @AlanBirtles I use gcc version=9. libstdc++11

Comment: @Jellyboy generator is cmake in this project

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys, I solved this problem.
It is because of the version of dependencies, just like @康桓瑋 said, I need to use C++17.
However, C++17 will lead to other conflicts. So I set

```
requires = "qt/5.15.2"
```

in conanfile.py instead of the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, it may help more people.